# Find row where keyword is like any reference in pg array of references

Tags: postgresql

Say I have this table of items and one column of type character *varying(255)[]* called references. There is also an index (GIN) for this column. The idea here is to easily store multiple references to the same item.

Now, I want to search for items where any reference is LIKE my keyword.

> Example:
>
> Item A has references [foobar, bazbaz].
> It should also find item A if I search for just 'foo%' or 'baz%'.

How would I do that while using the index and not going for a full table search?

**UPDATE**

Since I couldn't find an answer to this question, I went with some kind of a work-around:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE
references[1] LIKE :keyword OR
references[2] LIKE :keyword OR
references[3] LIKE :keyword
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible with the built-in indexes ... you may have to normalize and use a btree `text_pattern_ops`.

Comment: All your search-patterns are left-anchored like in the example?

Comment: yes, that's usually good enough

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need alias search. It is usually convinient to implement using FTS (full-text-search) built in PostgreSQL. I'll describe it brifely.

```
CREATE TABLE test.entity (pkey SERIAL NOT NULL, description text);
```

Then we create alias table. Our goal is to separate original entity from its aliases.

```
    CREATE TABLE test.aliases (
      talias tsquery NOT NULL,
      tentity tsquery,
    CONSTRAINT aliases_pkey PRIMARY KEY (talias)
    );
```

Let's insert some values

```
INSERT INTO test.entity (description) VALUES ('test');
INSERT INTO test.aliases VALUES (plainto_tsquery('test alias 1'), plainto_tsquery('test'));
INSERT INTO test.aliases VALUES (plainto_tsquery('test alias 2'), plainto_tsquery('test'));
```

And now there left only one question - how to search alias table? We'll use ts_rewrite to substitute query on the fly.

```
SELECT * FROM test.entity WHERE
        (SELECT ts_rewrite(plainto_tsquery('test alias 1'), 'SELECT talias, tentity FROM test.aliases')) @@  to_tsvector(description);

pkey | description
-----+----------------
   1 | test
```

Note, that you can use 'aliases' table for all aliases search in your system, use tsvector type instead of simple text in base entities table and create gin index on it.